# MySql "No password" Apache24 cant login

Tags: mysql, apache, localhost

In my MySQL server I have set my password to "no password" for the root.
When I tried to login via phpmyadmin (username: "root" password: " ") again This message popped up.

```
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)
```

So i went to my apache24 and opend `config.sample.inc.php` and changed

```
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

to

```
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

I restarted the MySQL server and I still have to same error.

Comment: `config.sample.inc.php` is a php file. I guess `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: You need to change mysql configuration separately if that's the problem, and also copy `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php` before editing. Editing the sample file won't affect it.

Comment: @BrahmaDev Thanks for your reply I just copied to 'config.sample.inc.php' to 'config.inc.php'. Still no effect. The myphpadmin is blocking me from logging in because I have to fill in a password.

Comment: Is it the same error ?

Comment: Solved, It was in folder config.default.php